# Call ASP.Net Core Web API from MS Teams Based Bot

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, asp.net-core-webapi

I have ASP.Net Core Web API which currently serving to my Web Application. In this API Cookie based Authentication is applied and my application is working smooth. Now I am developing a MS Teams based bot using Bot Framework and calling that Web API. It is returning me signing page every time I call that API. As in MS Teams we are already logged in how can I call that API directly?

For this I already have exposed my API to my registered bot application, and I also have tried with some permissions but no luck.

Comment: So, your application/API is needing/requiring a cookie. How does a client acquire a cookie for that? What criteria? Is this an AAD application? [This](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) sample shows how to integrate and authenticate users when using the Teams channel. Depending on your needs, that might help. If your API is an AAD application, the [msgraph](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) sample might help as well.

Comment: Yes it is AAD application

Comment: How does a client typically authenticate and acquire a cookie (outside of a bot situation)? What [auth flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios)(s) is this application setup configured for?